# How to remove ImageFilledPolygon php jagged edges?

Tags: php, gd

I have a function that fills a part of the bitmap created by imagecreatetruecolor($h,$w) ;
But the result is the drawing looking jagged and not smooth which sucks. 
I tried the php antialias(resource,boolean) function and there is no difference.  I can only guess it isn't supported.
Any gurus know of any neat trick to make the edges smooth? 
If you look at the image 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/images/21009b70229598c6a80eef8b45bf282b-imagefilledpolygon.png 
from the php manual, that is exactly what I mean. Any ideas how to remove it (the jagged edges)? 
Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the edges smooth, you can try the resizeimage function and add a blur parameter.

Comment: Hello, I tried it..didn't work. antialias(true) ; 
or do yo u speak of something else? Thanks

Comment: Spatial anti-aliasing is when you purposely make an image larger then it's intended, and then shrink it down to remove the aliasing and make it it's intended size.

Answer (score 2):

**@trimbo** [pointed out](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php#56521) in 2006 on `php.net`:

> You can still draw antialiased filled polygons by drawing a hollow
> polygon on top of a filled one with the same dimensions:
>
> ```
> $points=array($x,$y, $x2,$y2, $x3,$y3);
> imageFilledPolygon($im, $points, 3, $gray );
> imagePolygon($im, $points, 3, $gray );
> ```